# How do I get the Compose Extension Ellipsis button to show up with a custom side-loaded Microsoft Teams app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to learn how to create a Microsoft Teams app following their getting started guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-nodejs#ComposeRichMessages

Using the source code from here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs

I also read the specific docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/messaging-extensions

I have the app configured and packaged and side-loaded. The tabs and bot are functioning normally. However, the compose extension ellipsis button never shows up.

Supposedly, all I should need to do is set the correct `botId` in the `composeExtensions` section of the manifest.json. I did that, but it's still not showing up.

I have no clue how to troubleshoot this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs...

> **Important**
>
> messaging extensions are available only in Public Developer Preview. Many details in this document are subject to change.

That links to:

What is the Public Developer Preview for Microsoft Teams?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/general/developer-preview

Comment: When you turned on "Developer Preview" it worked, then?